# Passing and using an array by reference in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference, php-parse-error

In a PHP function, I'd like to append values to an array that was passed in by reference.  For example:

```
function foo(array &$arr) {
    $arr[] = "error on this line";
    $arr[] = "more";
    $arr[] = "stuff";
}
```

The error I get when I attempt to append something to the array is

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in somefile.class.php on line xxx
```

I'm not sure I have the parameter defined correctly, or if this is even possible.  Googling has so far not turned up any comparable examples.

**EDIT**:  PHP Version 5.1.6.

Comment: Is $arr declared as array?

Comment: Yes, it is.  It's used outside of this method, and is being populated in the same manner.  Because of that, I don't "know" the current index to use to append values.

Comment: I tried the function and it is working without any errors

Comment: what is you PHP version ? @Marvo

Comment: Your example function works just fine. Please expand your example code to a reproducible error.

Comment: PHP Version 5.1.6, so perhaps @paranoid-android has the solution below.  Seems to me that given that, the question should remain open.  I sadly don't get to choose the version of PHP we use.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with 5.1.6, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f161dc148a8fa7e4e5086c8e0ebdda1e95c32fd.

Comment: Looks like an error a dozen lines before it caused the parsing error.  But I'm happy to know about array_push().

Comment: Sorry everyone, ignore my vote to re-open; I hadn't expanded the list of comments; I thought what was missing was the PHP version, which was added later. Now I see that the error isn't in the listed code. Therefore, this is NOT a useful queston; Downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran your code and got the expected output, so I'm not sure what's happening. If `arr` wasn't an array, it wouldn't pass the typehint, so it's definitely an array.

**It's possible that you're running PHP < 5.4**

```
<?php

function foo(array &$arr) {
    $arr[] = "error on this line";
    $arr[] = "more";
    $arr[] = "stuff";
}

$a = ["initial"];

foo($a);

var_dump($a);

/*
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  string(7) "initial"
  [1] =>
  string(18) "error on this line"
  [2] =>
  string(4) "more"
  [3] =>
  string(5) "stuff"
}
*/
```

For PHP < 5.4:

```
<?php

function foo(array &$arr) {
    array_push($arr, "error on this line");
    array_push($arr, "more");
    array_push($arr, "stuff");
}

$a = array("initial");

foo($a);

var_dump($a);

/*
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  string(7) "initial"
  [1] =>
  string(18) "error on this line"
  [2] =>
  string(4) "more"
  [3] =>
  string(5) "stuff"
}
*/
```

Comment: You can't use short array syntax in PHP < 5.4.

Comment: That was the entire point I was trying to make. Just forgot to change the initialisation part as well (edited).

Comment: Also, you don't need `array_push` since `$arr[] =` is valid PHP 5.3 syntax.

Comment: Turns out I'm on 5.1.6.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_push

```
//The argument '$arr' is declared to be passed by reference, 
 array_push($arr, &$r);
```

You can check details here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* the "array" keyword before the parameter. The following code works for me:

```
$arr = array();

function foo(&$arr) {
    $arr[] = "error on this line";
    $arr[] = "more";
    $arr[] = "stuff";
}

foo($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Output:

`Array ( [0] => error on this line [1] => more [2] => stuff )`

EDIT: PHP-version is 5.6

Comment: FWIW: While its true that you don't need to use type hints in php, that is not relevant to the error in the question. (I'm sure it also worked on your php *with* the word "array", so this doesn't tell us anything about why it isn't working for the person asking the question.)